# How to stop a user from entering duplicate values

Tags: oracle, jakarta-ee, duplicates

In one of my Java EE applications, I used a registration page to register new user and as soon as one registers, his/her registered values will be inserted into Oracle database. But there is no way of detecting duplicate values. So I thought about adding `unique` constraint to  some column values. But later I learned, I can't declare more than one column as `unique`( In my case I already declared `userid` as **primary key**). But I need to make more than one column values *unique* (like `emialid` field).  Again only adding `unique` can't help as if a user submits a form with **duplicate value** an exception will be caught and user won't be able to understand as he will be redirected to a *blank page*. So I have 2 questions.

> 1) How can I inform the user about inserting duplicate values?

and

> 2) How can I make more than one column unique in Oracle?

**N.B.** I don't know javascript!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you certainly can declare multiple unique constraints on a table.  You can declare that `userid` is a primary key and then declare `emailid` as unique.  You can declare as many unique constraints as you'd like.

Second, your application would need to catch the duplicate key constraint and do something useful with it.  Redirecting the user to a blank page would not be useful-- your application ought to catch the constraint exception and present a useful message to the user.  For example, if you get an exception stating that the constraint `UK_EMAILID` was violated, you'd probably want to present an error message to the user saying something along the lines of "This email address already exists."

Comment: In my Oracle 10g I am getting error message `ORA-02261: such unique or primary key already exists in the table`

Comment: @SubirAdhikari - Can you post exactly what `DDL` you are executing to create the table and to create the constraints (please edit your question to include this information).

Comment: Ok. I solved the problem. The column was already `unique` which I was trying to make `unique`. Sorry for the inconvenience!!

Comment: One more request @JustinCave can you post some code snippet to show how can Icatch the exception of `UK_EMAILID` violated and show user "This email address already exists."

Comment: @SubirAdhikari - You'll need to describe your application architecture.  Are you writing straight JDBC?  Using JPA?  Something else?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JPA, you can build a unique constraints :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity_table_name", uniqueConstraints={
   @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"uniqueField1"}), // Unique value on one field.
   @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"uniqueField2", "uniqueField3"}) // Unique combination.
})
public class YourEntity {
  private Long id;
  private String uniqueField1;
  private String uniqueField2;
  private String uniqueField3;
  private String uniqueField4;

// ...
}
```

The implementation (hibernate, eclipseLink) will take care of the oracle part.